# mysterious indent 1px in Mac OS

Tags: html, macos, css

Have such a structure

```
<div class="container">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <aside class="right"></aside>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
}

aside {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    width: 63%;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    width: 37%;
    background: blue;
}
```

On windows all good. On Mac OS there is a 1px white line on the right, at the end of the blue block. On windows like when observed increases or decreases the zoom in the browser. Help get rid of this line please.

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z96odrfp/1/show/)

Upd - I have earning downvote, becouse of you dont see that issue. But I see that.. Mac OS Mountain Lion, I see that in Safari, sorry for no warn about browser.

You can also see [site](http://homeradar.hol.es/post.html), please, see right banner col and you'll see the problem

Comment: no white line here (mac OSX 10.9.4 / Chrome 37.0.2062.94)

Comment: have this on mac and chrome only when zooming 90%

Comment: What happens if you increase the width by .1% ? So 37.1%

Comment: I updated main question. @Doug its simply positioning under left col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing percentages with pixels (in this case, the left padding of the container, as shown in your Fiddle) usually leads to rounding problems of this sort. Either choose a % padding for the container, or add this to your CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

EDIT: based on the link provided, the following styles are recommended:

```
.post-cols {display: table}
.post-main-col, .banner-col {display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: I was referring to the Fiddle, where there is padding—and it's the px padding that's causing the issue.

Comment: Gotcha. It's not helpful when the Fiddle is different to the question >_> Sorry.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the answer a tad. :-)

Comment: Ralph, in fiddle I dont add normalize.css, but in site its on site, so I think the problem is not in this.

Comment: Yep, I see that now. Fair enough. But it all looks fine in Chrome to me. Only if I zoom the page down do I see a slight gap with the triangle top right, but I wouldn't worry about that personally. Are you sure your browser isn't zoomed? (I'm testing on Chrome for Mac.)

Comment: Yes, Im sure. I test it in Safari, in Chrome everything is fine, there only shown that line when zoomed.. But Safari show that line without zooming..

Comment: OK, it's an issue with pixel rounding. It's dangerous to use % widths when you need elements to fill a space tightly. My suggestion would be to set the container (`.post-cols`) to `display: table` and the divs inside it to `display: table-cell`. That helps them to fill the space nicely. Or you could float the columns left and right instead. Both work in Safari, but the table version a little better (and the media queries override this on smaller views already, so all good there.) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Ralph, I'll test it when can be near my work computer, and I'll tell you works it for me or not.

Comment: Thank you Ralph, this works fine. I mean `table-cell`s. But I dont understand, why problem with persentage... This is very bad bug..

Comment: Some browsers round up to the nearest px, some down. There's not much you can do about it, so avoid % widths when you need a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

Right I think I've found it for you. Works on all Zoom's for Chrome except 75%.

```
.main-section{
   margin-right: 64px; //Was 65px
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Doug.